# Why does a print statement in python multiprocessing drop CPU usage dramatically?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu

I am working with the multiprocessing library in Python and noticed that if I run a script like the one below, my CPU maxes out at 100%.

```
import multiprocessing

def test():
    for i in range(10000):
        j = i**i
        # print(j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for k in range(20):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
        p.start()
```

However, if I simply uncomment the print(j) line, the CPU usage drops to 10-15%. I'm just curious what is occurring at the hardware level with the print statement that limits the amount of CPU that I can utilize. When writing real code, I want to know what could limit the amount of resources I use and how I can avoid that. I have a Ryzen 5600X 6 core CPU.

Comment: print is slow and is blocked waiting on os resources ... simple math is not

Comment: Print out every 10 / 1000 / 10000.. iterations to see the CPU “efficiency” increase as print is reduced proportionally.

Comment: Things that print need to do: convert number to text, copy text to buffer, invoke system call.. then the console itself has to do the opposite and eventually display the value.

Comment: The system call performance is also limited by the speed in which the console can consume the stream, as it has to ensure that the operation is successful — redirecting to /dev/nul (or even a file) *might* change the observed CPU usage significantly. Would be easy to check.

Comment: as I know this problem exists in all languages - because problem makes system, not language. Standard solution is to print only ever 100 or 1000 iterations. You may also try to use directly to system `sys.stdout.write( str(j).decode() )` - but it may not give better result.